# In a Firebase A/B test, how exactly can you target a specific app version on Android?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-ab-testing

In "Targeting" section of a Firebase A/B test, you *should* be able to target by **version**:

> The version of the app (can vary by platform)

[image]

Is this supposed to use **`versionCode` or `versionName`** on Android? Simple question, yet I can't find the answer anywhere, and the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ab-testing/abtest-config?authuser=0#user_targeting) is useless in this regard.

My initial assumption was that *of course* it uses the numeric version code (e.g. 789). But I've tried both that and version name (e.g. 5.5.1), and **neither** seems to work — "0 users exposed"! (Or the delay before the report updates is very long.)

I've also been assuming that Firebase SDK automatically reads the version info, and it's not up to you as developer to programatically set it, but please correct me if I'm wrong!

I'm using Remote Config based A/B tests, should it make any difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right, turns out it uses **`versionName`**. (Experiment data was coming in with a long delay so it was hard to tell.)

You can use exact matches, "contains", and regexes:

[image: Screenshot of Firebase A/B test targeting section]